# ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor - single task/thread running often or multiple threads running less often

Tags: java, multithreading, amazon-sqs, threadpoolexecutor

I'm trying to set up a job that will run every x minutes/seconds/milliseconds/whatever and poll an Amazon SQS queue for messages to process. My question is what the best approach would be for this. Should I create a ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor with x number of threads and schedule a single task with scheduleAtFixedRate method and just run it very often (like 10 ms) so that multiple threads will be used when needed, or, as I am proposing to colleagues, create a ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor with x number of threads and then create multiple scheduled tasks at slightly offset intervals but running less often. This to me sounds like how the STPE was meant to be used.

Typically I use Spring/Quartz for this type of thing but that's out of at this point.

So what are your thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you use [long polling](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-long-polling.html) on SQS, which makes your `ReceiveMessage` calls behave more like calls to `take` on a `BlockingQueue` (which means that you won't need to use a scheduled task to poll from the queue - you just need a single thread that polls in an infinite loop, retrying if the connection times out)

Comment: Only problem is that doing this with a single thread can not keep up with the speed at which the queue is filling up.

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends on the frequency of tasks. If you just have to poll on timely interval and the interval is not very small, then `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` with `scheduleAtFixedRate` is a good alternative.

Else I will recommend using netty's `HashedWheelTimer`. Under heavy tasks it gives the best performance. Akka and play uses this for scheduling. This is because `STPE` for every task adding takes `O(log(n))` where as `HWT` takes `O(1)`.

If you have to use `STPE`, I will recommend one task at a rate else it results in excess resource.

Answer (score 0):

Long Polling is like a blocking queue only for a max of `20 seconds` after which the call returns. Long polling is sufficient if that is the max delay required between poll cycles. Beyond that you will need a scheduledExector.

The number of threads really depends on how fast you can process the received messages. If you can process the message really fast you need only a single thread. I have a setup as follows

1. `SingleThreadScheduledExecutor` with `scheduleWithFixedDelay` executes 5 mins after the previous completion
2. In each execution messages are retrieved in batch from SQS till there are no more messages to process (remember each batch receive a max of 10 messages).
3. The messages are processed and then deleted from queue.

For my scenario single thread is sufficient. If the backlog is increasing (for example, a network operation is required for each message which may involve waits), you might want to use multiple threads. If one processing node become resource constrained you could always start another instance (EC2 perhaps) to add more capacity.

Comment: So you wouldn't suggest to scale within a single app first before adding more instances? Seems like using a single thread in the app and adding more instances isn't a good use of the ec2 instance.

Comment: That sure is right and my answer does not suggest adding ec2 instances before existing capacity is utilized.